# ZxingObjc getting warning

Tags: ios, xcode5

i have new Zxingobjc in which int minPenalty = INT_MAX is already modified ,but still i am getting some 117 warnings in my project,most of them are implicit conversion loses integer precision 'NSUInteger (aka unsigned long) to int.

help me out.

Comment: So what's your exact problem? & what have you tried for it?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are getting the warning ? Probably you are assigning an NSUInteger to int variable (as written in the warning message)

Comment: - (void)encodeCompressedGtin:(NSMutableString *)buf currentPos:(int)currentPos {
  [buf appendString:@"(01)"];
  int initialPosition = [buf length];
  [buf appendString:@"9"];

  [self encodeCompressedGtinWithoutAI:buf currentPos:currentPos initialBufferPosition:initialPosition];
}

Comment: thats all warning are comin into Zxing files,and all i want to do is to scan QR code.

Comment: Please update your question with more details.

Comment: look i am getting 117 warning when i am running my code on xcode 5.0.2,and when i am running it on my device it is not showing a single warning.All the warnings are in Zxingobjc's files.thanks in advance